# Как в js подставить дату?

Tags: javascript

В форме получаю динамическую дату с помощью js

```
 <select name="date" class="form-control input-lg">
 <?php
 foreach($coins as $item) {
 $times = date('d.m.Y', $item['date']);
         
  echo '<option value="' . $times . '">' . $item['name'] . '</option>';
  
 }
 ?>
 </select>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker3">
        <input name="calendar" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
      <button id="ever" class="btn btn-default" title="Установить минимальную дату">
      </button>
    </div>
```

Дата хранится выше в `id="ever"` и изменяется динамически.

Как подставить эту дату в js заменить дефолтную дату 01.11.2017?

```
<script>

    
$('.form-control').on('change', function () {
var div = $('#ever');
div.text($(this).val());

//window.alert('#ever');

$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({ 
locale: 'ru',
format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
minDate: moment('01.11.2017').format('DD.MM.YYYY')
});

$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
locale: 'ru'
}); 

});
</script>
```

В select выбираю монету и у нее получаю дату. Для проверки даты вывел ее на кнопку `id="ever"`, дата изменяется, но как ее вставить в js код календаря (minDate), не знаю.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тут почитал справку, как я понимаю это от бутстрапа дата пикер. Можно просто установить `useCurrent: true`.

```js
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({ 
  locale: 'ru',
  format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
  useCurrent: true
});
```

---

UPD:
После комментария, задача немного изменилась. Я думаю как-то так?

```js
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'ru',
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
  });

$('.form-control').on('change', function() {
  let date = $(this).val();

  $('#ever').text(date);
  $('#datetimepicker3').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://itchief.ru/examples/libs/bootstrap-3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap DateTimePicker CSS -->
  <link href="https://itchief.ru/examples/vendors/bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://itchief.ru/examples/vendors/jquery/jquery-3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://itchief.ru/examples/libs/bootstrap-3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Moment -->
  <script src="https://itchief.ru/examples/vendors/moment/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap DateTimePicker -->
  <script src="https://itchief.ru/examples/vendors/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="date" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="20.05.2021">20 мая</option>
    <option value="22.05.2021">22 мая</option>
  </select>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker3">
      <input name="calendar" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <button id="ever" class="btn btn-default" title="Установить минимальную дату"></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124608/discussion-between-oliver-patterson-and-).